# Alternating row style for GridView not working after postback

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an Ajax Control Toolkit Tab container, and each TabPanel contains a GridView. The GridView is initially rendered with an alternating row style. After a PostBack, the GridView in the current active tab has an alternating row style and all the other tabs that weren't visible contain GridViews with no alternating row style.

How do I get the style to apply to the other GridViews even if they are in a tab that is not visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I can avoid this problem by setting the GridView's AlternatingRowStyle properties, I was using custom css before.